# How to query Identity EF tables with custom table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have below structure

[image]

Both users and roles are provided by injecting the IdentityUser and UserManager.

I have queried Student using the DBContext. Also, for users and roles, I have queries using UserManager.

But now I am struggling how to join both to query below

Find email of parent/s that is/are linked to Student S1 using EF?

```
var user = await _context.SolUserStudent.Where(a=>a.SolStudentId == request.Id).Include(a=>a.SolUsers.Email).ToListAsync();
```

Above gives me the all email ids including teachers. But not sure how to include condition where role = 'Parent'

Comment: btw I am injecting IdentityUser to SolUser Entity.

Comment: I am getting result with below. But how to convert this using EF?

SELECT TOP 
      [Email]

  FROM [model].[dbo].[AspNetUsers] A, [model].[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] B 
  where
  A.Id = B.UserId and B.RoleId = 'parent'
  and
 A.Id = (select UserId from [model].[dbo].[UserStudent] where StudentId = 'X')

Comment: Identity entities are like any other entities, so you query them like any other. Start from some `DbSet`, then follow navigations and do `Select`s or filtered `Include`, or other LINQ operators to get the desired result.